# SOAP request sent after receiving the Access Token gives "403 - Forbidden: Access is denied"

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, soap

I have started communicating with the Marketing Cloud API.

I have added a **Server-to-Server** integration component to our installed packages:

[image]

Using [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/), and the *Authorization Base URL* I receive the Access Token (a long string) that time-out after about 1079 seconds.

I found [this example page by Eliot Harper](https://gist.github.com/eliotharper/f29a78abba23020d8465) to use the Access Token to send a sample SOAP request to update an email address. The base URL I used to run this request is the *SOAP Base URL* and I run it using a `GET` method (even though I know SOAP request and responses probably don't have much to do with request verbs and work like XML envelopes). When I look at Eliot's page, I see he has used another URL for the SOAP request (`https://webservice.s7.exacttarget.com/Service.asmx` with the note that the `s7` value should be replaced with "SOAP endpoint", but my SOAP endpoint is a complete URL, so I'm a bit confused).

When I run the `GET` request with the URI provided in the image above I get the following response:

```
<body>
    <div id="header">
        <h1>Server Error</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        <div class="content-container">
            <fieldset>
                <h2>403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.</h2>
                <h3>You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.
                </h3>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

And if I replace the `s7` value in Eliot's URL with the `[THIS_VALUE]` in the SOAP URI (`https://[THIS_VALUE].soap.marketingcloudapis.com/`), I get the following response in Postman (again the verb is `GET`).

[image]

Can anyone help running a sample request?

**UPDATE**: Tested using username and pass as suggested by one of the comments. When I log into the marketing cloud the URL contains `s11`. So that's what I replace in the SOAP request. I get the following response using a GET.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <title>Error</title>
    <meta name="GENERATOR" content="Microsoft Visual Studio .NET 7.1" />
    <meta name="CODE_LANGUAGE" content="C#" />
    <meta name="vs_defaultClientScript" content="JavaScript" />
    <meta name="vs_targetSchema" content="http://schemas.microsoft.com/intellisense/ie5" />
</head>

<body style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; font-family: Arial;">
    <table style="height:100%; width:100%;" border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">
        <tr style="height:10%; background-color:#808080">
            <td>
                <div style="color:#ffffff; font-size: 16px;">An error has occurred and has been logged by our system.
                    <br />
                        Thank you. </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr valign="top">
            <td>
                <div id="errorTxt">&nbsp;</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>

</html>
```

**UPDATE 2**: The raw SOAP envelope I am sending using `POST`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soapenv:Header>
        <Security xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
            <UsernameToken>
                <Username>[MY_USERNAME]</Username>
                <Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">[MY_PASSWORD]</Password>
            </UsernameToken>
        </Security>
    </soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <UpdateRequest xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
            <Options>
                <SaveOptions>
                    <SaveOption>
                        <PropertyName>*</PropertyName>
                        <SaveAction>UpdateOnly</SaveAction>
                    </SaveOption>
                </SaveOptions>
            </Options>
            <Objects xsi:type="Subscriber">
                <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
                <ObjectID xsi:nil="true" />
                <EmailAddress>newemailaddress@mycompany.com</EmailAddress>
                <SubscriberKey>oldemailaddress@mycompany</SubscriberKey>
            </Objects>
        </UpdateRequest>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

The response I get is the same error in the picture above with dark background.

Comment: Verify that you have the correct permissions set for your User/Pass authentication: (3rd section down: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/authenticate-soap-api.htm) I personally use the token for all my calls, SOAP and REST as it is more secure and is fairly easy to 'automate' assigment of it in POSTman. I also would recommend using the 'personalized' SOAP API endpoint instead of the legacy one. This is returned in your token call and can be found in Admin in your BU.  E.g. `https://{{yourBUIdentifier}}.soap.marketingcloudapis.com/Service.asmx`

Comment: Stack 11 uses a TSE endpoint you can not simply plug in s11. You can find you endpoint by going to setup and look at your account settings

Comment: Adding a reference (look at top section talking about Tenant Endpoints) https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/wsdl-endpoint-links.htm and here for more info on Tenant Endpoints: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/your-subdomain-tenant-specific-endpoints.htm

Comment: @Gortonington Thank you for the comment. I will test your solution out and come back to you.

Answer (score -1):

The Endpoint you mention https://webservice.s7.exacttarget.com/Service.asmx is correct for the SOAP call, it is just not the endpoint of your Marketing Cloud instance. Instead of S7 as you are given at the example, use your own instance number, this can be found at the Marketing cloud URL when you login.

Example URL. "https://mc.s10.exacttarget.com/" here the server is S10, and that is all you have to change.

Also perhaps that one is not the only issue you have. Recently I have worked with SOAP calls with a Server to Server package and the Access token did not worked for me. I had to use the Username Token for authentication.

Example:

```
 <Header>
  <Security xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
     <UsernameToken>
        <Username>[YOUR USERNAME]</Username>
        <Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">[YOUR PASSWORD]</Password>
     </UsernameToken>
  </Security>
```

At your envelope's header you add the Security node with a Username and Password. This Username and Password needs to be from a User that it has the 'API User' checkbox enabled, at the User setup in Marketing cloud.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thank you! Let me test it out and come back to you.

Comment: Please check my updated question (the **UPDATE** part). I tried with username and password which is the user and pass I use for logging in. It was `s11` when I logged in to MC. My user is an API user. Also in my user settings there is a SOAP WSDL address as well as a SOAP Service Endpoint. But I unfortunately get the same response I added in the update.

Comment: Can you share the request you are sending? Also, if you make a SOAP call, it needs to be a POST request and not a GET, so you can send header parameters.

Comment: Please check **UPDATE 2**! I added the raw body of my envelope in Postman.

Comment: The request is the same as the one Eliot Harper used in his example.

Comment: Use a POST request and at the header set SoapAction = Update, also the Content-Type to text/xml

Comment: Sorry but I still get the message with dark background.